# Why is the output from a Cucumber Background shown only once?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I put a debug print statement in a Cucumber `Background` section.

Since `Background` is executed once for every scenario I expected to see output from the `Background` once for each scenario. However the output is shown only once. Why?

Here is a simple example that illustrates my question:

calculator/features/adding.feature:

```
Feature: Adding

Background:
  Given calculator is ready

Scenario: Add two numbers
  Given the input "2" and "2"
  When the calculator is run
  Then the output should be "4"

Scenario: Add another two numbers
  Given the input "2" and "3"
  When the calculator is run
  Then the output should be "5"
```

calculator/features/step_definitions/calculator_steps.rb:

```
counter = 0

Given(/^calculator is ready$/) do
  puts "*** background ***"
  counter += 1
end

Given(/^the input "([^"]*)" and "([^"]*)"$/) do |x1, x2|
  @x1 = x1
  @x2 = x2
end

When(/^the calculator is run$/) do
  @output = `ruby calc.rb #{@x1} #{@x2}`
end

Then(/^the output should be "([^"]*)"$/) do |expected_output|
  expect(@output).to eq(expected_output)
  puts "counter=#{counter}"
end
```

calculator/calc.rb:

```
x1 = ARGV[0].to_i
x2 = ARGV[1].to_i

print ("#{x1+x2}")
```

Here is the output when scenarios are executed:

```
$ cucumber
Feature: Adding

  Background:                 # features/adding.feature:3
    Given calculator is ready # features/step_definitions/calculator_steps.rb:3   
    *** background ***

  Scenario: Add two numbers       # features/adding.feature:6
    Given the input "2" and "2"   # features/step_definitions/calculator_steps.rb:8    
    When the calculator is run    # features/step_definitions/calculator_steps.rb:13
    Then the output should be "4" # features/step_definitions/calculator_steps.rb:17
      counter=1

  Scenario: Add another two numbers # features/adding.feature:11
    Given the input "2" and "3"     # features/step_definitions/calculator_steps.rb:8
    When the calculator is run      # features/step_definitions/calculator_steps.rb:13
    Then the output should be "5"   # features/step_definitions/calculator_steps.rb:17
      counter=2

2 scenarios (2 passed)
8 steps (8 passed)
0m0.094s
```

I expected to see the line `*** background ***` twice (because `Background` is executed twice), but it is only shown once. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages printed in Cucumber `Background` steps are printed only once because Cucumber captures standard output when it executes a step and prints it under Cucumber's control. Messages printed in `Background` steps are printed along with the step names: only once, at the beginning of the output.

The way to see printed messages every time the `Background` runs is the same, therefore, as the way to see the step names every time the `Background` runs. There was already a question and answer for that, but it doesn't work for the current version of Cucumber (I have 2.3.3), so I wrote a new answer to that question that shows [how to print everything that `Background` prints before every scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924488/how-to-output-cucumber-background-steps-within-scenarios/37117977#37117977).

Comment: Thanks Dave, solution you described for Cucumber 2.3.3 works for me, and since this is usually needed for debugging purposes it's not a problem to modify the gem locally.